# Возможно ли изменить ширину фигуры Svg <polygon>?

Tags: svg

Вот SVG изображение. В нем я пытаюсь уменьшить ширину

```
 <polygon id="life" class="green" points="951.3,104.5 930.5,140.5 333,140.5 333,53.5 1515,53.5 1485.5,104.5         "/>
```

Сниппет:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 1620 376" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1620 376;" xml:space="preserve">
   <style type="text/css">
      .green{fill:green;enable-background:new;}
   </style>
   <polygon id="life" class="green" points="951.3,104.5 930.5,140.5 333,140.5 333,53.5 1515,53.5 1485.5,104.5   "/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Из вопроса непонятно, какую ширину вы хотите уменьшить:*

- Уменьшить ширину самой фигуры, но насколько уменьшить не ясно.
- Уменьшить ширину места, которое занимает svg внутри HTML?

Если первый вариант, то необходимо в векторном редакторе перерисовать фигуру нужной ширины и длины. Для этого откройте векторный редактор, установите размер документа близкий по размерам нужной вам фигуры и в границах этого документа нарисуйте нужную фигуру, стараясь оставлять минимальные отступы от границ документа. Фигура очень простая и это будет вам не трудно.

Если это второй вариант,- вы не хотите перерисовывать фигуру, но вам надо уменьшить слишком большие отступы от фигуры до краев SVG, то можно воспользоваться следующей техникой:

Вот ваш SVG, красная рамка показывает границы svg документа.
 Она добавлена стилями: `style="border:1px solid red;"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 1620 376" style="border:1px solid red;">
   <style type="text/css">
      .green{fill:green;enable-background:new;}
   </style>
   <polygon id="life" class="green" points="951.3,104.5 930.5,140.5 333,140.5 333,53.5 1515,53.5 1485.5,104.5   "/>
</svg>
```

Видно, что присутствуют очень большие отступы от фигуры до краев svg документа. Какого размера красная рамка, столько места svg займет в HTML. И никакие ухищрения в CSS не помогут уменьшить эти отступы.  Уменьшать эти отступы нужно прямо в SVG. Для этого добавим `viewport` это `width` `height` в шапке svg файла. Если вам нужно адаптивное изображение, то ширину и высоту необходимо указывать в процентах.

*Для уменьшения отступов меняем соотношение сторон*,- делаем высоту в 8 раз меньше

`376 /8 = 47px` Точно такая же пропорция должна быть
у   `viewport`,-  `width="100"` `height="12.5%"`

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="100%" height="12.5%" viewBox="0 0 1620 47"  style="border:1px solid red;">
   <style type="text/css">
  .green{fill:green;enable-background:new;}
   </style>
   <g transform="translate(-300 -74)">
   <polygon id="life" class="green" points="951.3,104.5 930.5,140.5 333,140.5 333,53.5 1515,53.5 1485.5,104.5   "/>
</g>
   </svg>
```

`<g transform="translate(-300 -74)">` используется для более тонкой настройки положения фигуры.

**В частности, если хотите сделать более узкий полигон поднимите его этой командой вверх.**

```
<g transform="translate(-300 -80)">
```